# Fonts gone all faint on Stack Exchange?

Tags: bug

The text on Stack Exchange suddenly seems much thinner and weaker than before. Other websites and text appear to be normal.

Is it just me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Exchange switched from using a specified font in their stylesheet to using your browser default system fault on May 10, 2021. This would indeed change the appearance of the text on this site.

[We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021)

Comment: Well, I guess that explains the change, but not why it's so much weaker than other instances of San Fran.

Comment: Sadly, I'm probably the only one who gets to view the site in Lucida Grande.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy why are you the lucky one?

Comment: @Daniel Because it's the system UI font on Mavericks, and Chromium Legacy dutifully uses it when run on that OS.